# Export Data from Teradata to Excel Spread sheet

Tags: shell

Please find below my requirement.

1. Need to get data from Teradata and the result should be automatically pulled to an excel sheet.
2. A shell script should perform the above operation.

Right now I have connected to Teradata using shell script, not sure how I can pull the results to an excel sheet.

Comment: so what have you tried, please post your code, along with expected results, and errors, and we can try to help

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to export the result to CSV file.
A Direct export to Excel is not supported.

```
.LOGON localtd/dbc,dbc;
.EXPORT FILE = C:\TX\out.txt;
.SET RECORDMODE OFF;
.SET INDICDATA OFF;
.SET SEPARATOR ','

DATABASE databasename;
SELECT * FROM tablename;

.LOGOFF
.EXIT
```